# Query only retrieves one record

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I'm calling this query inside a `before_delete` handler, and the query only returns a **single** CampaignMember even when the Contact.Id is related to many CampaignMembers. When I run this query in anonymous execute it retrieves **multiple** CampaignMembers. How can I retrieve multiple related CampaignMembers while running this query in APEX?

```
public static void query(Map<Id, Contact> forDeletion) {
    Set<Id> contacts = forDeletion.keySet();
    for(CampaignMember campaignMember : [
            SELECT Contact.id,
            CampaignMember.customField_1,
            CampaignMember.customField_2,
            CampaignMember.customField_3,
            CampaignMember.customField_4,
            CampaignMember.customField_5
            FROM CampaignMember
            WHERE Contact.id IN :contacts]) {
        losingCampaignMembers.put(campaignMember.ContactId, campaignMember);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included all of the relevant code, but I'm guessing you have this declaration somewhere in your code:

```
static Map<Id, CampaignMember> losingCampaignMembers;
```

The thing is, you need the map value to be a `List<CampaignMember>`, because the relationship is *many-to-one*. So change the declaration to:

```
static Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>> losingCampaignMembers;
```

Additionally, you will need to change your algorithm. This type of grouping is common and often looks like:

```
for (CampaignMember child : [/*query*/])
{
    if (!groupedByParent.containsKey(child.ContactId))
    {
        groupedByParent.put(child.ContactId, new List<CampaignMember>());
    }
    groupedByParent.get(child.ContactId).add(child);
}
```

Comment: I get the same results even if I drop the query right in a `System.debug()`.

Comment: Change `Contact.Id` to `ContactId`. Never use the cross-object reference where you can just use the actual field value.

Comment: I changed it to `ContactId` and it retrieves the same results.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - A bit of an off topic performance thing but I remember this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179661/map-of-get-vs-containskey-efficient-check - all the time when I am checking maps for values in a loop like this. No longer use containsKey in these situations now.