# Creating Map of Unique Values and sObject List

Tags: apex

I have a list of [AccountTeamMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountteammember.htm) records coming into a trigger handler class. From this list, I need to create a Map where each item is a key with the unique account ID based on the AccountTeamMember.AccountId field and then a value with a list of AccountTeamMember records that are for that account.

Example:
**List of ATM records**

1. AtmID=100,AccountID=A001,UserId,U001
2. AtmID=101,AccountID=A001,UserId,U002
3. AtmID=102,AccountID=A002,UserId,U003
4. AtmID=103,AccountID=A002,UserId,U004
5. AtmID=104,AccountID=A003,UserId,U005

**Map of Account IDs and List of ATM records**

1. AccountID=A001, <AtmID=100, AtmId=101>
2. AccountID=A002, <AtmID=102, AtmId=103>
3. AccountID=A003, <AtmID=104>

How would I could about creating this Map with Apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a map of lists:

```
Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>> atmByAcctId = new Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>>();
for(AccountTeamMember record: someAtmList) {
  AccountTeamMember[] atmListForAcct = atmByAcctId.get(record.AccountId);
  if(atmListForAcct == null) {
    atmByAcctId.put(record.AccountId, atmListForAcct = new AccountTeamMember[0]);
  }
  atmListForAcct.add(record);
}
```

You'll want to remember this pattern, it's really common for many bulkification tasks.

Another common form you may find online reads like this:

```
Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>> atmByAcctId = new Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>>();
for(AccountTeamMember record: someAtmList) {
  if (!atmByAcctId.containsKey(record.Id)) { 
    atmByAcctId.put(record.Id, new AccountTeamMember[0]);
  }
  atmByAcctId.get(record.Id).add(record);
}
```

Some people prefer this form, but it is relatively slow and inefficient, as I talk about in more detail in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984).

In fact, it's so common, that I've used something like this as a generic method:

```
 public static Map<Object, List<sObject>> mapRecordsByField(sObject[] records, sObjectField field) {
   Map<Object, List<sObject>> results = new Map<Object, List<sObject>>();
   for(sObject record: records) {
     Object key = record.get(field);
     sObject[] recordsByValue = results.get(key);
     if(recordsByValue == null) {
       results.put(key, recordsByValue = new sObject[0]);
     }
     recordsByValue.add(record);
   }
   return results;
}
```

Comment: could you pls share documentation about the `recordsByValue = new sObject[0]` i see it for the first time and can't wrap my head around.

Comment: @Damecek assignment to a variable can then be used again. Consider this: `String a, b; a = b = 'Hello World';` We assign 'Hello World' to `b`, and then assign it to `a`. In other words, that line of code is shorthand for `recordsByValue = new sObject[0]; results.put(key, recordsByValue);`

Comment: thanks and that part `new sObject[0]`? i understand that it allocates a new list with first item being the record? but how does the compiler figures out that we want exactly the record variable and not some other within the scope?

Comment: @Damecek We're creating a new, empty list of type sObject. You can also write this as `new sObject[] {}`, `new List<sObject>()`, `new List<SObject>{}`, or `new List<sObject>(0)`. I write it as `new sObject[0];` as a personal preference (I come from a C/C++/Java background), but you can use whatever form you like best. The form I use is the shortest of all of them, and even though I type fast, I prefer to write shorter code on average.

Comment: Thanks, that was what i wanted to know.

Comment: @John_Henry Thanks for the suggested edit, but I wouldn't personally recommend that version, for performance reasons. You can read more about the problem with that version of code in [this answer I wrote](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984). While that version is slightly more legible, it's also 50% slower (approximately) than the version here. That said, I've included it here for completeness.