# How to rewrite that ternary operator code to if-else?

Tags: apex, code, operators, ternary-operator

I can't understand that part of the code - how to rewrite this to if-s and else?
Especially the part`this.map1?.containsKey(custom_object__c?.workflow_status__c)`

```
List<custom_object_2__c> listofSettngs = this.map1?.containsKey(custom_object__c?.workflow_status__c) ? this.map1?.get(custom_object__c?.workflow_status__c) : new List<custom_object_2__c>();
```

Comment: `partthis.map1?.containsKey(custom_object__c?.workflow_status__c)` is a condition that should go inside an IF statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?.` is the Safe Navigation Operator (SNO), which is used to return a null safely when a `NullPointerException` would occur. We can break it apart to make it easier to read:

```
List<custom_object_2__c> listofSettngs = this.map1
  ?.containsKey(custom_object__c?.workflow_status__c)
    ? this.map1?.get(custom_object__c?.workflow_status__c) 
    : new List<custom_object_2__c>();
```

This logic is incorrect. If the key has a null value, you won't end up with a new list. In other words, if the goal of this code is to always have a non-null result, it will fail if the map contains a null value for that key.

In addition, if `this.map1?.containsKey` is true, the `this.map1?.get` is unnecessarily paranoid. Alternatively, if `custom_object__c` is null, then you'd be trying to retrieve the null key, which might be unintentional.

Further, `null` isn't the same as `false` in Apex, so if the map was null, you'll still get a `NullPointerException`, because a condition must still be true or false, and not null.

The more appropriate version for this code would be:

```
custom_object_2__c[] listOfSettings =
  this.map1?.get(custom_object__c?.workflow_status__c);
if(listOfSettings == null) {
  listOfSettings = new custom_object_2__c[0];
}
```

If `map1` cannot be null, you can skip the first SNO, and if the parameter won't be null, you can skip the second SNO. Either way, we can cut out the `containsKey`, which is just a wasted check, since we're interested in making sure we don't end up with a null value after we're done.

[Related answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984).

Answer (score 0):

In `If` `else` world this will look like:

```
if(map1 != null && map1.containsKey(custom_object__c) && map1.get(custom_object__c) != null){
    listofSettngs = map1.get(custom_object__c).workflow_status__c;
} else {
    listofSettngs = new List<custom_object_2__c>();
}
```

Comment: Adding to Nagendra answer "?." is "safe navigation operator" which is used for null check that's why in answer map1.get(custom_object__c) !=null is checked

Comment: The containsKey is not necessary here, as I explain in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984). Retrieving a non-existent key with get does not throw an exception. There's also a logic bug involved here.

Comment: Correct. @sfdcfox. Null check is more than enough. I just converted the above ternary operator to if else.

Comment: @sfdcfox : For sharing how containsKey is not necessary. I was not aware of it at all