# Schedule Apex Class and "Apex CPU time limit exceeded"

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, cpulimit

This is the first scheduled apex class I've ever attempted, and I keep running into the "Apex CPU time limit exceeded" error. Once a month, I'd like for the system to look for past due invoices, and mark those accounts as "Past Due". The past due invoices are always in the thousands, and so are the accounts. Could that be it? Or is there something wrong with my code? Or is do we probably have a mess of automations in our org? I'll post my code here just in case. I appreciate any help or direction.

```
public class MonthlyPastDueAccounts_Class implements Schedulable{
public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
    List<gii__OrderInvoice__c> invList = new List< gii__OrderInvoice__c>();
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> updateList = new List<Account>();
    
    //Get past due invoice list
    invList = [SELECT Id, gii__Account__c FROM gii__OrderInvoice__c WHERE Past_Due__c NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Retainage', 'PAID', 'Current')];
    
    //Create past due account list
    for (gii__OrderInvoice__c i : invList)
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        
        acc.Id = i.gii__Account__c;
        
        if (!accList.contains(acc))
        {
            accList.add(acc);
        }
    }
    
    //Update accounts
    for (Account a : accList)
    {
        a.Past_Due__c = TRUE;
        updateList.add(a);
        }
        
        update updateList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have your `Schedulable` invoke a `Batchable` (could be the same class implementing both APIs) to do the processing. That way you process the overdue invoices in chunks that won't cause CPU or other limits to be violated.

Answer (score 5):

There is one line that looks troublesome to me
`if (!accList.contains(acc))`

`List.contains()`, to the best of my knowledge, performs a linear search. By having this inside of a loop, you've effectively made your code run in O(n^2) time. Make 'n' large enough, and it is feasible that could cause you to run into the CPU limit.

You should be using a `Map<Id, Account>` instead. By definition, a Map will never contain duplicate keys. Map's `containsKey()` is fast (O(1), or constant time, I believe), but you could get away with simply overwriting the current value in the map (if you do happen to come across a duplicate account).

```java
public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
    // Sets and Maps are what you want to use when you need to prevent duplicate
    //   data
    Map<Id, Account> acctMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    
    // Since it doesn't appear that you're using gii__OrderInvoice__c records
    //   for anything else here, you can just use the query to feed the loop
    //   directly.
    // This is called a "SOQL for loop", and it uses less heap space (and is
    //   less typing)
    for (gii__OrderInvoice__c invoice :[SELECT Id, gii__Account__c FROM gii__OrderInvoice__c WHERE Past_Due__c NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Retainage', 'PAID', 'Current')])
    {
        // Setting SObject fields in the constructor is fast (and less typing)
        Account acc = new Account(
            Id = invoice.gii__Account__c,
            // No need for a separate loop, just set the additional data here
            // Not really a concern in terms of speed, just less typing
            Past_Due__c = true
        );
        
        // If acc.Id already exists as a map key, .put() will just simply
        //   overwrite the current value stored for that key.
        acctMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
    }

    // We can't perform DML on a Map
    // ...but .values() returns a List (of the values stored in the map)
    //   which can
    update acctMap.values();
}
```

Comment: [See this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984) for performance characteristics. You're not quite wrong; list.contains and list.indexOf takes O(n) time, and Map.get/containsKey has something like O(√n) performance if you have decent key material. Because hashCode is used, there is a minimum threshold (about 16 values, if I recall) where list methods are faster, but large maps are far faster than large lists.