# how to pass the value in test class

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage, schedulebatch

batch class

```java
public class BillingSchemeRenewalWithoutAABatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
   public List<Billing_Scheme__c> list_BillingScheme=new List<Billing_Scheme__c>();
   public Map<String,Set<Id>> map_AccountDetails = new Map<String,Set<Id>>();
   public Map<String,String> map_BillingDetails = new Map<String,String>();
   public Map<Id,Set<Id>> map_AccountBillingIds = new Map<Id,Set<Id>>();




  // List<Account_Policy_Details__c> list_AccountPolicy=new List<Account_Policy_Details__c>();
   
   
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug('------Start------'); 

        String query = 'SELECT Id, Renewal_Date__c, End_Date__c, Expiration_Date__c'+      
                        ' FROM Billing_Scheme__c' +    
                        ' WHERE Renewal_Date__c = TODAY' +      
                        ' AND (Expiration_Date__c = null OR (Expiration_Date__c != null AND Expiration_Date__c > TODAY))' + 
                        ' AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Billing_Scheme__c FROM Account_Allowances__c)';

        System.debug('query==> ' + query);
        return Database.getqueryLocator(query);
    }

   
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Billing_Scheme__c> list_BillingScheme){
        System.debug('--Execute---');
        System.debug('list_BillingScheme==> ' + list_BillingScheme.size());
       
        Set<Id> set_BillingSchemeId = new Set<Id>();

        for(Billing_Scheme__c obj_BillingScheme : list_BillingScheme){
            //if(obj_BillingScheme.Account_Allowances__r.size() == 0){
                obj_BillingScheme.Renewal_Date__c = obj_BillingScheme.Renewal_Date__c.addYears(1);
                obj_BillingScheme.End_Date__c = obj_BillingScheme.Renewal_Date__c;
                set_BillingSchemeId.add(obj_BillingScheme.Id);
            //} 
        }
        
        BillingSchemeTriggerHelper.skipTrigger = true;
        Update list_BillingScheme; 
          
        createJson(set_BillingSchemeId, map_AccountDetails, map_BillingDetails, map_AccountBillingIds);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

        System.debug('<----finish---->');
        System.debug('map_AccountDetails--->' + map_AccountDetails);
        System.debug('map_BillingDetails ==> ' + map_BillingDetails);

        Map<String,String> map_ClientNameAndFinalJson = new Map<String,String>();
        if(map_AccountDetails.size()>0){ // how to pass the value here
            String strFinalJson = '';
            String key = '';
            //If first loop, we are getting key as : [apple, aviva_group, aviva_individual, ....]
            for(String strClientName : map_AccountDetails.keySet()){
                strFinalJson = '';
                System.debug('strClientName--->' + strClientName);

                //In second loop, we are getting key as account Id : 0011q00000bVsYG
                for(Id idAccoutObj : map_AccountDetails.get(strClientName)){
                    System.debug('idAccoutObj--->' + idAccoutObj);
                    if(map_AccountBillingIds.containsKey(idAccoutObj)){
                        //In third loop, we are getting key as Billing Scheme Id : a0R1q000005ZoxR
                        for(Id idBillingScheme : map_AccountBillingIds.get(idAccoutObj)){
                            //eg: key = '0011q00000bVsYG-a0R1q000005ZoxR'
                            key = idAccoutObj + '-' +idBillingScheme;
                            if(map_BillingDetails.containsKey(key)){
                                strFinalJson = strFinalJson + map_BillingDetails.get(key) + ',';
                            } 
                        }
                    }   
                }
                
                System.debug('strFinalJson--->' + strFinalJson);
                
                if(String.isNotBlank(strFinalJson)){
                    strFinalJson = strFinalJson.subString(0, strFinalJson.length()-1);
                    strFinalJson = '{ "AccountRenewal":['+ strFinalJson + ']}';   
                    map_ClientNameAndFinalJson.put(strClientName, strFinalJson);
                }
                System.debug('map_ClientNameAndFinalJson--->' + map_ClientNameAndFinalJson);

            }  
        }

        System.debug('map_AccountDetails==> ' + map_AccountDetails.size());
        
        if(map_AccountDetails.size()>0){
            BillingSchemeRenewalWithoutAABatch.callAccountRenewalRestAPI(map_ClientNameAndFinalJson);
       }
    }

    public static void createJson(Set<Id> set_BillingSchemeId, Map<String,Set<Id>> map_AccountDetails, Map<String,String> map_BillingDetails, Map<Id,Set<Id>> map_AccountBillingIds){
        System.debug(' -- Create Json -- ');
        System.debug('--set_BillingSchemeId ==> ' + set_BillingSchemeId.size());

        Map<Id, Account> map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate = new Map<Id, Account>(); //This map update GIP_Policy_Anniversary_Date__c on Account.    
        
        for (Account_Policy_Details__c obj_AccountPolicyDetails : [
            SELECT id,Instructing_Party__c,
            Billing_Scheme__c, Billing_Scheme__r.Renewal_Date__c,
            Instructing_Party__r.Referrer__r.Client_Name__c, 
            Instructing_Party__r.Referrer__r.Slug__c 
            FROM Account_Policy_Details__c 
            WHERE Billing_Scheme__c IN:set_BillingSchemeId
        ]) {
            String key = '';
            String strJson = '';
            String strAccountBillingkey = '';
            String str_AccountId = obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Instructing_Party__c;
            String str_BillingSchemeId = obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Billing_Scheme__c;
            String clientName = obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Instructing_Party__r.Referrer__r.Client_Name__c;

            if(obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Instructing_Party__r.Referrer__r.Slug__c == Label.UNUM_Referrer_Slug 
                && !map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.containsKey(str_AccountId)
            ){
                Account objAcc =  new Account(
                    Id = str_AccountId
                );
                objAcc.GIP_Policy_Anniversary_Date__c = obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Billing_Scheme__r.Renewal_Date__c;
                map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.put(str_AccountId,objAcc);
            }
            
            strAccountBillingkey = str_AccountId  + '-' + str_BillingSchemeId; 

            if(!map_BillingDetails.containsKey(strAccountBillingkey)){

                Set<Id> set_BillingIds = null;

                if(map_AccountBillingIds.containsKey(str_AccountId)){
                    set_BillingIds = map_AccountBillingIds.get(str_AccountId);
                }else{
                    set_BillingIds = new Set<Id>();
                }

                set_BillingIds.add(str_BillingSchemeId);
                map_AccountBillingIds.put(str_AccountId, set_BillingIds);
                
                if(obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Instructing_Party__r.Referrer__c!=null && String.isNotBlank(clientName)){
                    key = clientName;
                }else{
                    key = 'BLANK';
                }

                Set<Id> set_AccountId = new Set<Id>();
                if(map_AccountDetails.containsKey(key)){
                    set_AccountId = map_AccountDetails.get(key);
                }
                set_AccountId.add(str_AccountId);
                map_AccountDetails.put(key, set_AccountId);

                System.debug('map_AccountDetails--->' + map_AccountDetails);

                strJson = '{"accountId": "' + str_AccountId + 
                        '", "billingSchemeId": "' + str_BillingSchemeId + '"' ;
    
                String strDate = '';
                Date startDate = null;
                Date endDate = obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Billing_Scheme__r.Renewal_Date__c;

                if(endDate!=null){  
                    startDate = obj_AccountPolicyDetails.Billing_Scheme__r.Renewal_Date__c.addYears(-1); 
                    strDate = startDate + '';
                    strDate = strDate.subString(0,10);
                    strJson = strJson + ', "newStartDate": "' + strDate + '"' ;
                }else{
                    strJson = strJson + ', "newStartDate": ""' ;
                }
                if(endDate!=null){   
                    strDate = endDate + '';
                    strDate = strDate.subString(0,10);
                    strJson = strJson + ', "newEndDate": "' + strDate +'"}';
                }else{
                    strJson = strJson + ', "newEndDate": ""}';
                }
                
                map_BillingDetails.put(strAccountBillingkey, strJson);
                System.debug('strJson--->' + strJson);
            }    
        } 

        if(map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.size()>0){
            update map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.values();
        }
        System.debug('map_BillingDetails ==> ' + map_BillingDetails);
        System.debug('map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.size()-----> ' + map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.size()); 
    }

    public static void callAccountRenewalRestAPI(Map<String,String> map_ClientNameAndFinalJson){
        System.debug('map_ClientNameAndFinalJson--->' + map_ClientNameAndFinalJson);
        String toEmailAddress = '';
        Map<String, String> map_SuccessResponse = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> map_FailResponse = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<String,Accounts_Renewal__c> map_Configuration = new Map<String,Accounts_Renewal__c>();
        
        for(Accounts_Renewal__c objConfig : [select id, Name, API_key__c, End_Point_URL__c, To_Email_Address__c from Accounts_Renewal__c order by Name]){
            map_Configuration.put(objConfig.Name.toLowerCase(), objConfig);
        }
        
        System.debug('map_Configuration---->' + map_Configuration);
        
        if(map_Configuration.size()>0 && map_ClientNameAndFinalJson.size()>0){
            for(String strClientName : map_ClientNameAndFinalJson.keySet()){
                try{
                    System.debug('strClientName---->' + strClientName);
                    if(map_Configuration.containsKey(strClientName.toLowerCase())){
                        Accounts_Renewal__c objConfig = map_Configuration.get(strClientName.toLowerCase());
                        System.debug('objConfig---->' + objConfig);
                        if(String.isBlank(toEmailAddress)){
                            toEmailAddress = objConfig.To_Email_Address__c;
                        }
                        Http http = new Http();
                        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                        request.setEndpoint(objConfig.End_Point_URL__c);
                        request.setMethod('POST');
                        request.setHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');
                        request.setHeader('x-api-key', objConfig.API_key__c);
                        request.setHeader('x-client-name', strClientName);
                        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        request.setBody(map_ClientNameAndFinalJson.get(strClientName));
                        request.setTimeout(120000);
                        HttpResponse response = null; 
                        
                        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                            response = http.send(request);
                        }
                        System.debug('response---------> '  +response);
                        
                        if(response!=null){
                            if(response.getStatusCode()==200){
                                map_SuccessResponse.put(strClientName, response.getBody());
                            }else{
                                map_FailResponse.put(strClientName, response.getBody());
                            }
                        }
                        
                        //This line of code, only for code coverage.
                        if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                            map_SuccessResponse.put(strClientName, 'Test Class');
                            map_FailResponse.put(strClientName, 'Test Class');
                        }
                    }    
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.debug('Exception error---> ' + ex);
                    map_FailResponse.put(strClientName, ex + '');
                }
            }
            
            if(String.isBlank(toEmailAddress)){
                toEmailAddress = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
            } 

            Integer intCount = 1;
            //Send Email to System Admin when json response will be succeeded.
            if(map_SuccessResponse.size()>0){
                //Also send JSON as a file attachment.
                String strAddtionalMsg = '';
                intCount = 1;
                List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> list_Attachment = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
                
                for(String strClientName : map_SuccessResponse.keySet()){
                    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment objFile = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                    objFile.setFileName(strClientName + '_JSON.txt');
                    objFile.setBody(Blob.valueof(map_ClientNameAndFinalJson.get(strClientName)));
                    list_Attachment.add(objFile);
                    strAddtionalMsg = strAddtionalMsg + '\n' + intCount +') ' + strClientName + ' (API Response) : ' + map_SuccessResponse.get(strClientName);
                    intCount = intCount + 1;
                }

                String strEmailSubject = 'Rest API Succeeded';
                String strEmailBody = 'Hi Admin, \n\n' + 'Rest API successfully executed. \n'+ strAddtionalMsg;
                strEmailBody = strEmailBody + '\n\n' + 'For more information, please find attached json file.';
                
                BillingSchemeRenewalBatch.sendEmailToSystemAdmin(toEmailAddress, strEmailSubject, strEmailBody, list_Attachment);
                
            }
            
            //Send Email to System Admin when json response will be Failed.
            if(map_FailResponse.size()>0){
                //Also send JSON as a file attachment.
                String strAddtionalMsg = '';
                intCount = 1;
                List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> list_Attachment = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
                
                for(String strClientName : map_FailResponse.keySet()){
                    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment objFile = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                    objFile.setFileName(strClientName + '_JSON.txt');
                    objFile.setBody(Blob.valueof(map_ClientNameAndFinalJson.get(strClientName)));
                    list_Attachment.add(objFile);
                    strAddtionalMsg = strAddtionalMsg + '\n' + intCount +') ' + strClientName + ' (API Response) : ' + map_FailResponse.get(strClientName);
                    intCount = intCount + 1;
                }
                
                String strEmailSubject = 'Rest API Failed';
                String strEmailBody = 'Hi Admin, \n\n' + 'Rest API throw below-mentioned error: \n' + strAddtionalMsg;
                strEmailBody = strEmailBody + '\n\n' + 'For more information, please find attached json file.';
                
                BillingSchemeRenewalBatch.sendEmailToSystemAdmin(toEmailAddress, strEmailSubject, strEmailBody, list_Attachment);
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void sendEmailToSystemAdmin(String strToAddresses, String strEmailSubject, String strEmailBody, List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> list_Attachment){
        List<String> list_ToAddresses = strToAddresses.split(';');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setSubject(strEmailSubject);
        email.setPlainTextBody(strEmailBody);
        email.setToAddresses(list_ToAddresses);
        if(list_Attachment!=null && list_Attachment.size()>0){
            email.setFileAttachments(list_Attachment);
        }
        
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
        }
    }
    
}
```

my test class

```
@isTest
public class BillingSchemeRenewalWithoutAABatchTest implements HttpCalloutMock {    
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('Success');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }

    @TestSetup
    
    static void setupData(){
        List<Account> list_Acc = new List<Account>();
        List<Account__c> list_CustAccount = new List<Account__c>();
        List<Products__c> productList = new List<Products__c>();
        List<Account_Allowances__c> list_AccountAllowances = new List<Account_Allowances__c>();
        Referrer__c refObj = new Referrer__c(
            Name='Unum', 
            Slug__c='Unum', 
            Active__c=true,
            Client_Name__c='Unum'
        );
        insert refObj;

        Account accountObj = new Account(
            Name='Test Party 1', 
            Referrer__c=refObj.Id, 
            Status__c='Active'
        );
        list_Acc.add(accountObj);

        Account accountObj1 = new Account(
            Name='Test Party 2', 
            Referrer__c=refObj.Id, 
            Status__c='Active'
        );
        list_Acc.add(accountObj1);
        insert list_Acc;

        Account__c obj_CustomAccount = new Account__c(Instructing_Party__c=accountObj.Id);
        Account__c obj_CustomAccount1 = new Account__c(Instructing_Party__c=accountObj1.Id);
        list_CustAccount.add(obj_CustomAccount);
        list_CustAccount.add(obj_CustomAccount1);
        insert list_CustAccount;
        
        Products__c obj_Product = new Products__c(Name='Product', Active__c=true);
        Products__c obj_Product1 = new Products__c(Name='Product1', Active__c=true);
        productList.add(obj_Product);
        productList.add(obj_Product1);
        insert productList;

        Billing_Scheme__c objBillingScheme = new Billing_Scheme__c(
            Name= 'ABC Billing Scheme demo',
            Active__c = true,
            Base_Price__c = 200,
            Billing_Scheme_ID__c = '1112',
            Billing_Scheme_Information__c = 'TATA_LIMITED',
            Currency__c = 'GBP',
            Duration__c = 'Fixed Date',
            End_Date__c = Date.Today(),
            Health_Points__c = 20,
            Paid_By__c = 'Instructing Party',
            Renewal_Date__c = Date.Today(),
            Scheme_Type__c = 'Allowance',
            Start_Date__c = Date.Today(),
            VAT__c = 20
        );
        insert objBillingScheme;

        Billing_Scheme__c objBillingScheme1 = new Billing_Scheme__c(
            Name= 'ABC Billing Scheme demo1',
            Active__c = true,
            Base_Price__c = 200,
            Billing_Scheme_ID__c = '11123',
            Billing_Scheme_Information__c = 'TATA_LIMITED1',
            Currency__c = 'GBP',
            Duration__c = 'Fixed Date',
            End_Date__c = Date.Today(),
            Health_Points__c = 20,
            Paid_By__c = 'Instructing Party',
            Renewal_Date__c = Date.Today(),
            Scheme_Type__c = 'Allowance',
            Start_Date__c = Date.Today(),
            VAT__c = 20
        );
        insert objBillingScheme1;

        Account_Policy_Details__c acntPlcyDtals = new Account_Policy_Details__c(
            Instructing_Party__c=accountObj.Id,
            Billing_Scheme__c=objBillingScheme.Id
        );
        insert acntPlcyDtals;

        Account_Allowances__c aw = new Account_Allowances__c(
            Account__c=obj_CustomAccount.id,
            From__c=Date.today(),
            Max_Allownace__c=5,
            Remaining_Allowance__c=5,
            Is_Active__c=true,
            Products__c=obj_Product.Id,
            To__c=Date.today(),
            Auto_Renewal__c=True,
            Billing_Scheme__c = objBillingScheme.Id
        );

        Account_Allowances__c aw1 = new Account_Allowances__c(
            Account__c=obj_CustomAccount1.id,
            From__c=Date.today(),
            Max_Allownace__c=5,
            Remaining_Allowance__c=5,
            Is_Active__c=true,
            Products__c=obj_Product.Id,
            To__c=Date.today(),
            Auto_Renewal__c=True,
            Billing_Scheme__c = objBillingScheme.Id
        );

        list_AccountAllowances.add(aw);
        list_AccountAllowances.add(aw1);
        insert list_AccountAllowances;    
    }  
    @isTest
    public static void TestMethod1() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BillingSchemeRenewalWithoutAABatchTest());
        Test.startTest();
        List<Billing_Scheme__c>updatedBs=[SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Account_Allowances__r) From Billing_Scheme__c WHERE Renewal_Date__c=TODAY AND (Expiration_Date__c = null OR (Expiration_Date__c!=null AND Expiration_Date__c>TODAY)) and name='ABC Billing Scheme demo'];
        System.assertEquals(1,updatedBs.size());
        
       
        BillingSchemeRenewalWithoutAASch bswas= new BillingSchemeRenewalWithoutAASch();
        String cronExpr = '0 0 3 * * ?';
        String jobId = System.schedule('Test', cronExpr, bswas);
        bswas.execute(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

here my code covered is only 15% i unable to pass value in line number 75 in batch class please help me for 75%

Comment: I unable to pass the value in finish method (if(map_AccountDetails.size()>0){) from test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is filtering with:

```
Id NOT IN (SELECT Billing_Scheme__c FROM Account_Allowances__c)
```

Which appears to exclude all of the Billing Scheme records you created. Consequently, the execute method isn't called, so:

```
if(map_AccountDetails.size()>0){ // how to pass the value here
```

is false, and so most of your code doesn't do anything. You need to fix `@testSetup` so that you have at least one Billing Scheme that's not attached to an Account Allowances.

---

Some feedback on your code follows.

---

## Code Legibility

`list_BillingScheme` is known as a form of Hungarian notation. If you can, I would suggest avoiding this. It's usually sufficient to just say `billingSchemes` instead. Your code should be legible enough that Hungarian notation is just wasted space.

For example, instead of writing `map_AccountBillingIds`, which doesn't actually tell me how this variable is being used, you could say `billingSchemeIdsByAccountId`. Yes, this is longer, but it tells me precisely what I expect to find in this Map.

Be descriptive in your variable, method, and class names. Further, you're not even applying it consistently, sometimes `str_SomeName` and other times `strSomeName`. Consistency leads to legible code.

`map_ClientNameAndFinalJson` is another name I find misleading. A Map of Client Name and JSON? That doesn't mean what I know it is, it's just messy. Just call it `payload`, `requestData`, or something. A bad variable name doesn't help developers figure out what's going on.

---

## Database.getQueryLocator query

The `String query` version of this is not recommended if you don't need it. It's far too easy to forget a space or have other typos. Use an inline query if possible. Also, your filters were overly verbose. I've taken out the extra bits you don't need.

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getqueryLocator([
        SELECT Renewal_Date__c, End_Date__c, Expiration_Date__c
        FROM Billing_Scheme__c
        WHERE Renewal_Date__c = TODAY AND 
        (Expiration_Date__c = null OR Expiration_Date__c > TODAY) 
        AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Billing_Scheme__c FROM Account_Allowances__c)
    ]);
}
```

---

## Redundant Parameters

```
createJson(set_BillingSchemeId, map_AccountDetails, map_BillingDetails, map_AccountBillingIds);
```

Could have simply been called as:

```
createJson(set_BillingSchemeId);
```

And the method signature would then be:

```
public static void createJson(Set<Id> set_BillingSchemeId) {
```

Because parameters are pass by reference for objects, this coincidentally worked, but be aware that when you write parameters or local variables with the same name as class-level variables, you're introducing [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm). When you do that, you then have to write `this.` to get at the class variable. As a trivial example:

```
public class X {
  public Account y;
  public void someMethod(Account y) {
    y.Name = 'Contoso';
  }
}
```

...

```
X var = new X();
var.y = new Account();
Account z = new Account();
var.someMethod(z);
System.assertEquals(z.name, 'Contoso'); // This passes
System.assertEquals(y.name, 'Contoso'); // This fails
```

Avoid doing this, because it makes it unclear what variable is being accessed, especially in code this long.

---

## Fake JSON

A lot of your extra code is related to faking JSON. At no point are you calling `JSON.serialize` to create your JSON. There's a lot of opportunities for you to screw things up. Hint: You should never have a `strFinalJson` variable unless it's through a `JSON.serialize`.

```
String[] billingDetailValues = new String[0];
...
billingDetailValues.add(map_BillingDetails.get(key));
...
Map<String, Object> payloadData = new Map<String, Object> {
  'AccountRenewal' => billingDetailValues
};
if(!billingDetailValues.isEmpty()) {
  String payloadJSON = JSON.serialize(payloadData);
  // omitted for brevity.
}
```

---

## containsKey/get Optimization

[I've said it before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984), I'll say it again. Don't use both `containsKey` and `get`. It's much more efficient to use `get` and a null check.

### Example 1

```
Set<Id> set_BillingIds = null;

if(map_AccountBillingIds.containsKey(str_AccountId)){
    set_BillingIds = map_AccountBillingIds.get(str_AccountId);
}else{
    set_BillingIds = new Set<Id>();
}
```

Can be:

```
Set<Id> billingIds = billingSchemeIdsByAccountId.get(accountId);
if(billingIds == null) {
  billingSchemeIdsByAccountId.put(accountId, billingIds = new Set<Id>());
}
```

### Example 2

```
if(map_BillingDetails.containsKey(key)){
    strFinalJson = strFinalJson + map_BillingDetails.get(key) + ',';
}
```

Can be:

```
String billingDetailValue = map_BillingDetails.get(key);
if(billingDetailValue != null) {
  billingDetailValus.add(billingDetailValue);
}
```

And again, I'll put it here that this String should have been a `Map<String, Object>` so you can just serialize everything at the end. You're wasting a lot of extra memory and CPU resources by doing a lot of string concatenation prematurely.

However, I'm actually not convinced that the value can ever be null, which leads me to...

---

## Useless Null Checks

It seems to me that a lot of the various checks to see if things can be null or keys can be found are redundant/useless. As a trivial example, we wouldn't normally write:

```
Integer x = 5, y = 10, z;
if(x != null && y != null) {
  z = y / x;
}
```

We already know that both values aren't null in this case, because we initialized them properly. You should always strive to [Say "No" to "Null"](https://elegantcode.com/2010/05/01/say-no-to-null/). You should be able to reduce your code significantly by just by minimizing your null checks. They're out of control.

---

## Long Try-Catch

```
try {
   // 39 lines later ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug('Exception error---> ' + ex);
    map_FailResponse.put(strClientName, ex + '');
}
```

You're not sure of your failure models, so just capture everything and hope for the best? That's not good. Try to limit your try-catch blocks to as small as possible, and specific exceptions, if possible. Once you understand your code better, you can reduce or even eliminate most try-catch blocks.

## Test Code in Live Code

```
//This line of code, only for code coverage.
if(Test.isRunningTest()){
    map_SuccessResponse.put(strClientName, 'Test Class');
    map_FailResponse.put(strClientName, 'Test Class');
}
```

You should almost never do this. If your mock responses are working correctly, your code will run "as if" it had called the server and got a valid response (or a failure mode, if you're testing the error handling).

---

## Waiting Too Long

```
request.setTimeout(120000);
```

Keep in mind that the 120 second callout limit is cumulative. If your API is taking too long, you might need to reduce your batch size or get the API fixed. Otherwise, you should definitely shave this down to a smaller size so that one bad callout doesn't kill your entire transaction. You cannot "catch" governor limits.

## Useless Null Assignment

```
HttpResponse response = null;
```

Is strictly equivalent to:

```
HttpResponse response;
```

Local variables are always null until you assign a value to them.

---

## Unnecessary Guardrails

```
if(map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.size()>0){
    update map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.values();
}
```

Is basically the same as:

```
update map_UpdateUNUMAccountAnniversaryDate.values();
```

It uses slightly more CPU time, but not noticeably so, and won't burn DML governor limits if the collection is empty. I'm also not entirely sure you could even run into a situation where the map is empty anyways, so it's just wasted space.

## Don't Forget the Debug Statements

Debug statements, especially on large collections, can eat up a lot of CPU time. Make sure you remove those before deploying to production.

## Don't Forget to Test in Bulk

You're not using enough records; make sure you create a test that has at least 100 records so you can find out where your breaking point is. This isn't something you want to wait until it goes to production to find out that the data volumes are crashing your code.

## Unrestricted Queries

```
for(Accounts_Renewal__c objConfig : [select id, Name, API_key__c, End_Point_URL__c, To_Email_Address__c from Accounts_Renewal__c order by Name]){
    map_Configuration.put(objConfig.Name.toLowerCase(), objConfig);
}
```

You need to filter this so that you'll only find records that could possibly be relevant to your logic. It looks like this should be fine:

```
for(Accounts_Renewal__c objConfig : [
    select Name, API_key__c, End_Point_URL__c, To_Email_Address__c from Accounts_Renewal__c 
    where name in :map_ClientNameAndFinalJson.keySet()]) {
    map_Configuration.put(objConfig.Name.toLowerCase(), objConfig);
}
```

## Empty Loops Are Okay

```
if(map_AccountDetails.size()>0){ // how to pass the value here
```

You don't need to check an empty loop before you iterate over it:

```
Integer[] values = new Integer[0];
for(Integer value: values) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Sometimes it's useful to do so if it means saving governor limits (e.g. a useless query), but you don't need to do it all the time.

## Avoid Excessive Concatenation

As stated earlier, JSON building by hand is a bad idea, but so is arbitrary concatenation.

```
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + '\n\n' + 'For more information, please find attached json file.';
```

Can be:

```
strEmailBody += '\n\nFor more information, please find attached json file.';
```

You should only use this technique to break up a really long string.

Comment: a masterwork in proper coding style - this should be a canonical q&a